# When is equilibrium analysis appropriate?

Tags: equilibrium

What is a good rule of thumb to use to determine if equilibrium is the appropriate assumption?  I assume it is mainly to do with the time scales of the problem, meaning if the reaction time scales are very short, we could probably assume that we get to equilibrium very quickly.  Is there an accepted metric for determining if the equilibrium assumption is valid?

Comment: Are you asking how long it takes to reach equilibrium?

Comment: bon - That is part of my question, but the other part is what other factors would prevent this assumption.  For example, if one of the system elementary reactions included an irreversible reaction, I would assume equilibrium analysis would not be ideal.

Comment: An irreversible reaction still goes to equilibrium. It's just the equilibrium is so far to the right that only a negligible amount of reactants will remain once it is reached.

Comment: Understanding this sort of time scale analysis is one of the key skills to learn in graduate chemical engineering transport phenomena classes: e.g., https://stellar.mit.edu/S/course/10/fa14/10.50/index.html.

Comment: Brian - I had tried looking into online course content.  Unfortunately the 10.50 website requires the mit kerbos certificate, and the OCW and DSpace versions don't have much of the course content posted.  Can you recommend any other online course resources?  I'm currently working through Dewitt (heat transfer & transport).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context.

The accepted threshold is "when everything else is slow by comparison." For example, if you have a reaction that takes place in two parts, a Jones oxidation taking a secondary alcohol to a ketone and Diels-Alder (which is far slower), you can assume for modeling purposes that the oxidation will be in equilibrium whenever you're looking at how the Diels-Alder will interact with the oxidation.

By contrast, if you're reacting something like a $\ce{CN7}$ anion (which will react very very quickly, detonating with no provocation), the Jones oxidation can't be considered in equilibrium by comparison.

Comment: This sounds similar to the arguments for the partial equilibrium approximation.  Compare the relative reaction rates (timescales), the fast reactions are assumed in equilibrium and the slow reactions are assumed to be the rate limiting step.  Can a similar argument be applied to flowing systems, meaning if the timescales for the reactants to flow through the system are faster than the reaction timescales, I can assume a frozen flow, but if the flow is relatively slow I assume it is in equilibrium?  If so what's a good metric for "faster", 1 order of magnitude ?

Comment: That sounds about right. And the metric for "faster" is generally "as loose as I can get away with." Modeling multiple reactions not at equilibrium at once is quite a bit more complicated than just assuming one reaction is at equilibrium, so as long as the excuse exists, the assumption will generally be that one of the reactions is at equilibrium. There isn't a set quantitative cut off point though.

Comment: One clarification: If multiple phenomena have 'fast' time scales, then they will *inter-*equilibrate.  Also, one has to think a bit about the time scale on which one is interested in the dynamics of the system.  Any processes 'significantly faster' than this time scale can generally be assumed to always hold at mutual equilibrium.